# Rhetorical Paper

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I am writing a rhetorical response to a film and find myself often using the phrase "the viewer"; are there any ways to make my argument more direct without using "the audience" or "the viewer"?

Comment: Could you use 'we' or 'I'?

Comment: If it's a paper, they'll understand you constantly using "the viewer", especially if your grader doesn't like you using the first person. It may be awkward, but you don't have a lot of alternatives. "We" would probably be fine if it's not an extremely formal paper. "I" would rarely be correct because that's probably too informal.

Answer (score 2):

The most "inclusive" word to use is "***we***." "I" implies a personal, not all-inclusive, point of view--which is *not* what you want to imply in a "review."